# Element Actions for Entries being viewed from modifyEntrySources

Tags: entries, plugins, hook

Im using the modifyEntrySources hook in my plugin, when I view the entries based on my custom criteria it doesn't show the checkboxes for element actions, is there a way to get these back or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The checkboxes will only show up if there is at least one available [element action](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/element-actions) for the current source.

Element actions are defined by element types’ [getAvailableActions()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/elementtypes/IElementType#getAvailableActions-detail) methods, which will vary their response based on the `$source` that is passed in.

In [EntryElementType’s](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/elementtypes/EntryElementType) case, if an unrecognized `$source` is passed in, then no actions will be returned.

However, [EntryElementType::getAvailableActions()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/elementtypes/EntryElementType#getAvailableActions-detail) does have a hook called [addEntryActions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#addEntryActions), which gives plugins the opportunity to add additional actions to its response.

So on top of using the [modifyEntrySources](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySources) hook, you can also use the addEntryActions hook to provide the actions that your custom source should have.

```php
public function addEntryActions($source)
{
    if ($source == 'myCustomSourceKey')
    {
        $elementType = craft()->elements->getElementType(ElementType::Entry);
        return $elementType->getAvailableActions('section:X');
    }
}
```

(Replace `X` with the ID of a section you want to mimic.)

Comment: Ahhhh! Awesome, thanks Brandon! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Hey Brandon, I just tried this out. With a help from looking in the resources tab in chrome developer tools and the handy die() function, the addEntryActions doesn't seem to be running on my custom source keys, runs on the system sources though fine...

Comment: Ah yes, sorry you're right. I'll tweak that for the next release!